# Comparing two ids from two tables in php using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, compare

This is the SQL statement I have written.

```
$result_array 
   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_fixtures WHERE id = pl_divisions.id", $con1);
```

It is written to compare values of dbfix.id with dbdiv.id. Can someone please tell me what is my error in comparing these two "id"s? dbfix and dbdiv are two different tables in a same database. Both have id as primary keys. I am using PHP 5.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Regards,
BG

Comment: Give the desired output and data sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't including the pl_divisions table in your select. Try the following:

```
$result_array = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_fixtures, pl_divisions WHERE pl_fixtures.id = pl_divisions.id", $con1);
```

Comment: Aaaaah...That is the effect of friday ;) Thank a lot Steerpike :) :) :)